# Get absolute URL with Grape-Api gem on Rack app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm doing an API with [grape gem](https://github.com/intridea/grape), in one of my services I would like to retrieve the complete URL. For example if the user does request on :

```
api.myapp.com/android/users.json
```

I would like be able to retrieve  `api.myapp.com/android/users.json` or at least `/android/users.json`

```
class MyApp::API::Users < Grape::API

    resource :users do

        get do
            request.original_url
            # stuff ...
        end
    end
end
```

I tried what I know from Rails, but now it's Grape and it doesn't work :

```
  "error": "undefined method `original_url' for #<Grape::Request:0x00000005a78c08>"
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do the same thing (generate absolute URIs) within my own API and after much research, I eventually gave up. There is, amazingly, no good way I can find to get the information you're looking for out of Grape—you cannot, for instance, specify a resource is "mounted" at a specific path and then retrieve that information later.

What I wound up doing in the meantime was saving the base URL (scheme, hostname and port) in a global variable at the start of each request:

```
before do
  # Save the base URL of the request, used by resources to build
  # their canonical URI
  Resources::base_url = request.base_url
end
```

and then, within each resource representer, "manually" assembling the URI using hardcoded path information:

```
link :self do
  RideYork::API::Resources::base_url +
    "/resources/agencies/#{represented.id}" if represented.id
end
```

It's a terrible hack, but I'm not aware of a better solution.

Comment: I understand what you suggest, but it doesn't fit in my case. I have two apps (one on android and one ios) and I would like they send request on `api.myapp.com/android/users.json` or `api.myapp.com/iphone/users.json` in order to know on the server side which type of device is requesting. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Well, normally you'd use an HTTP header to identify which kind of client is connecting—it's considered bad form to have multiple URIs that point to different representations of the same underlying resource. Have you looked into using the [`User-Agent`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43)  header for this purpose?

Comment: When I did. And I will probably do like you say.

Answer (score 3):

[`Grape::Request`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/grape/0.9.0/frames) is just a [`Rack::Request`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request).  It looks like the `Rack::Request` has a [`#url`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request#url-instance_method) method you could try.

Comment: You're almost right, but it returns `http://api2.myapp.com/users.json` when I type `http://api2.myapp.com/android/users.json`

Comment: Well the docs say it "tries" to recreate that URL, so some information must be lost...  Are you behind a proxy like nginx or anything?  You could try the `#headers` method and see if anything useful is in there.

Comment: Nothing more with `headers` method. I use nginx and maybe I did wrong with my rewrite ?
`location /android {
      rewrite /android/(.*) /$1  break;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://api2;

    }`

Comment: that's exactly what you've asked: /android/users.json is rewritten as /users.json

Comment: yes but I would like to get what the user request /android or /something